# merge 2 xelements objects and get a merged xelement object in c#

Tags: c#

I have 2 objects of type XElement :

The first one is like this :

```
<Groups xmlns="groups.xsd">
    <Group Name="A">    
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">    
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

The second one is like this :

```
<GroupsInformation xmlns="groupsinformation.xsd">
    <Group Name="A">
        <number>10</number>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">  
        <number>15</number> 
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

I would like to juste merge the 2 documents without any transformation and get a new XElement object like this :

```
<Groups xmlns="groups.xsd">
    <Group Name="A">    
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">    
    </Group>
</Groups>
<GroupsInformation xmlns="groupsinformation.xsd">
    <Group Name="A">
        <number>10</number>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">  
        <number>15</number> 
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

or like this (as I don't know if an Xelement can have 2 namespaces) :

```
<Groups xmlns="groups.xsd">
    <Group Name="A">    
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">    
    </Group>
</Groups>
<GroupsInformation>
    <Group Name="A">
        <number>10</number>
    </Group>
    <Group Name="B">  
        <number>15</number> 
    </Group>
</Groups>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem?

```
var first = XElement.Load(...);
var second = XElement.Load(...);

var merged = new XElement("Merged", first, second);
```

The final document will have two namespaces.